# Error in building MobileVLCKit

Tags: ios, vlc, libvlc

I'm trying to build **MobileVLC** on **OS X Leopard**, using **iOS SDK 4.3**.

Followed the given instructions, however, build stops and fails here: `[info] Building contrib for iOS in '/Users/matp/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib-builddir-ios-arm-apple-darwin10'`

```
Current log:./buildMobileVLC.sh 
[info] Preparing build dirs
[info] Building
[info] Building vlc
[info] Building libvlc for the iOS
[info] Using armv7 with SDK version 4.3
[info] Building contrib for iOS in '/Users/matp/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib-builddir-ios-arm-apple-darwin10'
```

The error is given as follows:

```
make[1]: *** [.ffmpeg] Error 1
make: *** [using-src] Error 2
/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib-builddir-ios-arm-apple-darwin10/build-src/ffmpeg/config.log tells me:

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/matp/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib-ios-arm-apple-darwin10/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/matp/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/vlc/contrib-ios-arm-apple-darwin10/lib'
ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib for architecture armv7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
C compiler test failed.
```

Also before changing in order to get this far with the sdk 4.3 I had to change the sdk in `buildMobileVLC.sh` to 4.3 from 4.2. Before the change I got the error:

```
xcodebuild: error: SDK "iphoneos4.2" cannot be located.
```

How do I fix this error? and can fixing the `xcodebuild` error in a different way fix both of the problems?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: ImportedSources/vlc/extras/contrib/bootstrap

Add:
EXTRA_LDFLAGS="${EXTRA_LDFLAGS} -isysroot ${IOS_SDK_ROOT}"

Before:

if test -z "$IOS_SDK_ROOT"; then
      error "The bootstrap script requires the IOS_SDK_ROOT environment "
      error "variable to be set when building for iOS"
      exit 1
fi

Answer (score 1):

two method:
1. you’d better install iOS SDK 4.2 from package Xcode 3.2.5／3.26

1. edit your script, ./MobileVLC/build_for_iOS.sh , change 4.2 -> 4.3

after that you might go further